# Trigger events in Internext Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've created an element:

```
jHTML = '<span id="spnID">text</span>';
objUlThumbs.append(jHTML);
```

and then bind an event to it:

```
    $('#spnID').bind('click', function () {
            // some code like:
            //     windows.uninstall("ie.exe");
            //     windows.install("chrome.exe");
            //     alert("NOW you have a browser! for GOD sake.");
    });
```

Now, I'm trying to trigger this event elsewhere in the page:

```
$('#spnID').trigger('click'); // or simply: $('#spnID').click();
```

It works well in all browsers, not in IE - which does nothing.
I've tried also live() and a simple click(funcion(){...}) instead of bind() - doesn't work as well.

Well, is there a solution for this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Which versions of IE have you tested this in?

Comment: I've tested this in IE8 (windows xp). And yes, I'm doing this in document.ready().

Comment: This is working for me in IE8 (per http://jsfiddle.net/AuaCr/)

Comment: It must be something else that is wrong. This is working for me in IE6, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead for the 1st line:

```
jHTML = $('<span>',{id: 'spnID', text: 'text'});
objUlThumbs.append(jHTML);
```

and then what you can do is:

```
jhtml.bind('click', function () {
        // some code like:
        //     windows.uninstall("ie.exe");
        //     windows.install("chrome.exe");
        //     alert("NOW you have a browser! for GOD sake.");
});
```

Comment: Not really answering his question though is it.

Comment: @tfbox, and why isnt it? IE renders object differently

Comment: @tfbox, never said there was. but this might work, downvote if you think i am wrong. again, IE creates DOM elements differently

Comment: @Neal I'm not going to downvote, it's good you're giving an answer. But really the way the jHTML variable is done already will make no difference, but good luck with your answer.

Comment: @Neal, It works! I changed all my jQuery-html-changes to the append method, and now I can trigger events in IE too. Thank you!